# Can & How Can I Install Windows 7 x64 on a MacBook Air?

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, macbook

Is it possible ?

Are there any issues ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **EDIT:**  You don't need a SuperDrive, any
>   External Optical Drive will do.  I
>   have a SuperDrive and a Buffalo
>   External Drive.  I do not recommend
>   buying a SuperDrive EVER; as other
>   drives suffice, and if you ever have
>   issues with a bad boot sector (as I
>   have) you cannot boot from the drive
>   and use an external HDD to copy your
>   data off the internal HDD.

Apple does not support x64 on a MacBook Air, but you can, and I have installed Windows 7 x64 Home Premium.

You will be asked to install a 32bit Version of Windows; which I ignored, following [Gizmodo's Install Guide](http://gizmodo.com/5387353/how-to-survive-boot-camp-and-run-win-7-on-a-mac)

Upon a subsequent install, running `setup.exe` directly will not work because Apple has disabled it for the MacBook Air, running it results in ...

> "Boot Camp x64 is unsupported on this
>   computer model"

#### ... but being unsupported doesn't mean it doesn't work! :)

Issues to resolve are that you will require a two button mouse or keyboard with a right click equivalent, the latter being my solution to get to the menus.

#### Use ["Compatibility Mode"](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/316-compatibility-mode.html) to install:

#### `<optical-drive-letter>:\Boot Camp\Drivers\Apple\BootCamp64.msi`.

Answer (score 1):

Friends of mine run VMware fusion and are very happy with Windows 7 on that, I think they are running 32-bit editions but I did see [this post](http://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2009/01/windows-7-on-mac-with-vmware-fusion-a-practical-guide.html) that says that 32-bit and 64-bit editions of Windows 7 Beta were supported on VMware fusion so I'd suspect it should handle the released version on Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 0):

It's possible using boot camp. The hard part is the lack of CD drive. If you have an external CD drive, it's just like installing anything else with Boot Camp. Apparently [network installs don't work](http://blogs.msdn.com/volkerw/archive/2009/01/19/installing-windows-7-on-a-macbook-air.aspx), and neither do USB installs. The best idea I heard was to buy a superdrive, install Windows 7, then return the drive (or borrow one from a friend if you're that lucky)..