# How do I install Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro without a SuperDrive?

Tags: windows-7, installation, usb-flash-drive, macbook-pro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can & How Can I Install Windows 7 x64 on a MacBook Air?](https://superuser.com/questions/76820/can-how-can-i-install-windows-7-x64-on-a-macbook-air)

I have a MacBook Pro Mid-1010 (which, from what I can tell, doesn't support USB booting (except Apple's [Recovery Disk Assistant](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4848) boots just fine off a USB drive). I took out the SuperDrive, moved the original 250GB hard drive to the SuperDrive bay, and installed a new 750GB hard drive in place of the original. I then used the aforementioned Disk Assistant to completely copy the 250GB hard drive onto a partition on the 750GB hard drive. I now want to install Windows 7 on the 250GB hard drive.

However, as I don't have a SuperDrive, I can't boot off the Windows 7 disc, and since my MacBook apparently doesn't support USB booting, I can't boot that way either. So I'm stuck.

Apparently I can use VirtualBox to start the install, then reboot onto the actual drive and go from there; however, information on this process is unreliable and outdated at best, and looks to require reFIT, which appears to be completely useless to me and would complicate further upgrades and such.

So, am I SOL here? I'd like to avoid having to install the SuperDrive again and swap around the drives, then do it again after I'm done, and I'm not even sure if the Windows install DVD will boot straight off the disc without BootCamp.

Comment: TL;DR - You don't need a SuperDrive, any External Optical Drive will do

Comment: So if I put the SuperDrive back in and mount the 250GB drive in its default place, the Windows 7 install disc will boot just fine? Is that my only option here?

Comment: Don't ask me; Read the answer to the "possible duplicate". If that doesn't work,come back here and [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/466734/edit) your question to indicate what you tried and what went wrong and you'll probably get more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Boot Camp to install Window 7. You can use any external optical drive or you can create a bootable flash drive with Windows 7.

Here are directions for creating an image from an existing Windows 7 image, which you will obviously need an optical drive for. If you absolutely cannot get access to an optical drive, there are ways to go about downloading the .iso file from the internet. I personally use PowerISO but you can user any disc utility software.

PowerISO tutorial and download: 
http://www.poweriso.com/tutorials/iso-maker.htm

And here are directions on how to create a bootable USB flash drive:
http://arstechnica.com/business/2009/12/the-usb-flash-drive/

Using Boot Camp to install Windows 7:
http://www.simplehelp.net/2009/01/15/using-boot-camp-to-install-windows-7-on-your-mac-the-complete-walkthrough/